# Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format

Tags: macos, tar, macos-mojave, opentok

I have a shell script to download OpenTok framework:

```
curl -L "https://tokbox.com/downloads/OpenTok-iOS-2.18.0.tar.bz2" | tar -xj
```

Although it downloads the .bz2 file, it gives back an error:

> Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format.

So unarchiving doesn't happen even if I manually try using the archive utility. It gives an error saying unsupported format.

I tried

```
tar -xvf file.bz2
```

on the terminal to see if it unarchives the downloaded file. I also tried installing bzip2 through brew. Nothing is working out, and I am unable to fix this issue.

Comment: Download the file and check what is the actual format `file file.tar.bz2`

Answer (score 1):

It was the file access permission which was creating issue. Once I navigated to desktop folder command executed fine.